# Thread Local remove() in Spring Boot webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, thread-local

I have a Web Filter that sets an object in a ThreadLocal attribute and I'm trying to understand how/when this Thread local should be cleaned-up (ThreadLocal.remove()) to avoid the exception "User context already initiated." that happens because it is being retrieved from the Spring Boot Thread Pool with the previous values set.

I'm using Spring Webflux.

Where can I hook this SecurityAuthorizationContext.clean() call?

```
public class SecurityAuthorizationContext
{
    private static final ThreadLocal<PrivilegeHolder> userContext = new ThreadLocal<>();

    private final List<String> roles;

    private SecurityAuthorizationContext(List<String> roles)
    {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public static void create(List<String> roles)
    {
        if (nonNull(userContext.get()))
        {
            log.error("User context already initiated.");
            throw new AuthorizationException("User context already initiated.");
        }

        PrivilegeHolder privilegeHolder = new PrivilegeHolder();
        userContext.set(privilegeHolder);

        // example of privileges retrieved from database by the user roles
        privilegeHolder.add(INSERT);
        privilegeHolder.add(DELETE);
    }

    public static void clean()
    {
        userContext.remove();
    }

    public static boolean hasInsertPrivilege()
    {
        return userContext.get().hasPrivilege(INSERT);
    }

    public static boolean hasDeletePrivilege()
    {
        return userContext.get().hasPrivilege(DELETE);
    } 
}
```

---

```
public class AuthorizationFilter implements OrderedWebFilter
{
    private static final String USER_ROLES = "user-roles";

    @Override
    public int getOrder()
    {
        return SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION.getOrder();
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain)
    {
        ServerHttpRequest request = serverWebExchange.getRequest();
        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();

        List<String> roles = headers.get(USER_ROLES);

        SecurityAuthorizationContext.create(roles);

        return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
    }        
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConfiguration
{    
    @Autowired
    private AuthorizationFilter authorizationFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http)
    {
        return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilterAt(authorizationFilter, AUTHORIZATION)
            .build();
    }    
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: Long story short ...  I just want to extract something from request headers and make it available to all the stack without passing it as parameter.

Comment: Webflux might switch thread whenever it wants to so using thread local is not safe as the information in threadlocal might be lost at any time. It looks to me you are trying to implement a custom security context. Why implement something that already exists

Comment: Yes, the thread pool in reactive flow messes it up. You might be right about reinventing the wheel here, but I'm trying to understand how it would be in a reactive world. I just want to extract something from request headers and make it available to all the stack without passing it as parameter (I updated my post quoting it)

Comment: Then read the reactor reference documentation. What you are looking for is called the ”context” or ”reactive context”

Answer (score 1):

So, better to use reactor context instead of ThreadLocal, here you can read about: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context